# Can't enter utilities when rebooting?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, recovery, utilities

For some reasons I need to disable System Integrity Protection (SIP). But when I try to enter utilities by rebooting my Mac with Command+R, I get an earth icon and a message about recovering from internet.

After an extremely long time waiting nothing seems to happen.

All I want to do is go to Utilities so I can disable SIP. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,the method is through USB,Create a bootable installer for macOS,the detail is in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372, （download macOS from AppStore is extremely faster than internet recovery）when create finished,reboot your mac with that USB flash disk insert,pressing the Option keys during bootup,then chose the yellow disk named install macOS ,after an language chose interface，can finally enter utilities

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, it sounds like your booting your Mac to start up from macOS Recovery over the Internet.

If this is what's happening, then your most likely pressing the <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> keys during bootup (instead of just <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>).

If you're absolutely sure that you're only pressing the <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> keys, then perhaps try using the <kbd>Command</kbd> key on the other side of the keyboard (in case you've got a problem with your keys).

By the way, the full process to disable SIP is:

1. Start your computer
2. Immediately hold down the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> keys to boot into 
   recovery
3. Click the Utilities menu and select Terminal
4. Type `csrutil disable` and press <kbd>return</kbd>
5. Close the Terminal app
6. Select Restart.... from the menu

Let me know if this helps or if you're still having problems doing this.

Comment: I tried all the combine and change of keys,but it always goto the same earth and said "starting internet recovery this may take a while",and my router shows the download speed was only 50~70KB/S....

Comment: What happens when you hold the Option button down while booting up? What options do you get to boot from?

Comment: I solved the problem finally,through downloading Sierra from AppStore(can up to about 8MB/S),and make a USB flash disk driver and finally succeed to enter Utilities.Still Thanks For Your Answer!

Comment: @Jingxizi You should put your comment in an answer and accept it so others can find it.